# NumPy: grid to full coordinate set

Tags: python, numpy

How do I go from a shape (either `np.mgrid` or `np.indices`) to actual coordinate vectors if I don't know the number of axes up front? If you know APL, this is its [index generator](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/index.htm#Language/Primitive%20Functions/Index%20Generator.htm) (`⍳`) primitive.

Example: in the 2d case, I want to go from

```
>>> np.indices((2, 2))
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
```

to

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1],
 [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

So it's a concatenate reduction over axis 0. In APL, I can express that just so:

```
yx
┌┌→──┐
↓↓0 0│
││1 1│
││   │
││0 1│
││0 1│
└└~──┘
,⌿yx ⍝ Catenate reduce-first-axis
┌→────────────┐
↓ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │0 0│ │0 1│ │
│ └~──┘ └~──┘ │
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │1 0│ │1 1│ │
│ └~──┘ └~──┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

(or of course the built-in `⍳` directly)

```
⍳2 2
┌→────────────┐
↓ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │0 0│ │0 1│ │
│ └~──┘ └~──┘ │
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │1 0│ │1 1│ │
│ └~──┘ └~──┘ │
└∊────────────┘
```

Comment: `np.moveaxis(np.indices((2, 3, 4)), 0, -1)`?

Comment: Or with its dyadic transpose: `np.indices((2,2)).transpose(1,0,2)`.  And closer to  your concatenate example,  `np.stack(np.indices((2,2)),1)`

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, but it would rather be `idxs.transpose(1, 2, 0)` and `np.stack(idxs, -1)` to produce the expected result. And only the `stack` variation satisfy the "unknown number of axes" constraint. `moveaxis` is faster also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need this particular order?

Consider a 2d array:

```
In [81]: arr = np.arange(1,5).reshape(2,2); arr
Out[81]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

With `indices` (or `mgrid`) we can index `arr` in the same order with:

```
In [82]: idx = np.indices((2,2)); idx
Out[82]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])

In [83]: arr[idx[0],idx[1]]
Out[83]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

If we move the first dimension last, we have adjust the indexing accordingly:

```
In [84]: idx1 =np.moveaxis(idx, 0, -1); idx1
Out[84]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[1, 0],
        [1, 1]]])

In [85]: arr[idx1[...,0],idx1[...,1]]
Out[85]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

`meshgrid` produces a list of arrays that work in the same way:

```
In [86]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(2),np.arange(2), indexing='ij')
Out[86]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [1, 1]]),
 array([[0, 1],
        [0, 1]])]
```

The base Python `itertools.product` generates values in your preferred order (after a reshape to (2,2,2)):

```
In [98]: list(product([0,1],repeat=2))
Out[98]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: I’m actually writing an APL interpreter on top of numpy, which is why I want to emulate the output of APL’s index generator. But I’m finding that numpy and APL’s array models are sufficiently distinct to make it feel a bit gritty.

Comment: I used APL professionally in the 1980s, STSC on pcs.  Then went on to use MATLAB in grad school. Now on SO I mostly  follow numpy.

Comment: Pop in and say hi on https://apl.chat